# How to call a function with a struct parameter

Tags: solidity

```
    struct MigrateParams {
        address pair; // the Uniswap v2-compatible pair
        uint256 liquidityToMigrate; // expected to be balanceOf(msg.sender)
        uint8 percentageToMigrate; // represented as a numerator over 100
        address token0;
        address token1;
        uint24 fee;
        int24 tickLower;
        int24 tickUpper;
        uint256 amount0Min; // must be discounted by percentageToMigrate
        uint256 amount1Min; // must be discounted by percentageToMigrate
        address recipient;
        uint256 deadline;
        bool refundAsETH;
    }
```

```
function migrate(MigrateParams calldata params) external {code}
```

How should I call "migrate" this function

this is my code

```
    function callFunc() public {
        MigrateParams memory mig;
        mig.pair = address(this;
        mig.liquidityToMigrate = 40872475671826880538328523;
        mig.percentageToMigrate = 1;
        mig.token0 = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;
        mig.token1 = 0xC3afDe95B6Eb9ba8553cDAea6645D45fB3a7FAF5;
        mig.fee = 500;
        mig.tickLower = 100;
        mig.tickUpper = 100;
        mig.amount0Min = 0;
        mig.amount1Min = 0;
        mig.recipient = address(this);
        mig.deadline = 8888888898993;
        mig.refundAsETH = true;

        token.migrate(mig);
    }
```

But the compilation doesn't pass, I can't call like this, This problem is really bothering me, can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not specify the compilation error or how `token` variable is defined, I will paste a working example that you can directly use on remix.

My best guess is that you haven't defined the interface of `token`. The interface defines the functions that can be called externally to the contract.

Note: You should first deploy `Token` contract and then `Contract` with the `Token`'s address as an input.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.12;

struct MigrateParams {
    address pair; // the Uniswap v2-compatible pair
    uint256 liquidityToMigrate; // expected to be balanceOf(msg.sender)
    uint8 percentageToMigrate; // represented as a numerator over 100
    address token0;
    address token1;
    uint24 fee;
    int24 tickLower;
    int24 tickUpper;
    uint256 amount0Min; // must be discounted by percentageToMigrate
    uint256 amount1Min; // must be discounted by percentageToMigrate
    address recipient;
    uint256 deadline;
    bool refundAsETH;
}

interface IToken {
    function migrate(MigrateParams calldata params) external;
}

contract Token {
    function migrate(MigrateParams calldata params) external {
        // code
        return;
    }
}

contract Contract{
    
    IToken public token;

    constructor(IToken _token){
        token = _token;
    }

    function callFunc() public {
        MigrateParams memory mig;
        mig.pair = address(this);
        mig.liquidityToMigrate = 40872475671826880538328523;
        mig.percentageToMigrate = 1;
        mig.token0 = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;
        mig.token1 = 0xC3afDe95B6Eb9ba8553cDAea6645D45fB3a7FAF5;
        mig.fee = 500;
        mig.tickLower = 100;
        mig.tickUpper = 100;
        mig.amount0Min = 0;
        mig.amount1Min = 0;
        mig.recipient = address(this);
        mig.deadline = 8888888898993;
        mig.refundAsETH = true;

        token.migrate(mig);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ser, this works, I originally wrote the struct in the interface, so the compilation failed, your code inspired me, it worked ❤️